# run an executable file through python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, os.system

I am working on running an executable through python to connect to a cyberarc vault. When i run executable in command line it works, but in python i am not able to get the result.

I have tried both os.system and subprocess but no help.

Please help

```
import os
import subprocess
prg = "D:\File\CyberArk\ApplicationPasswordSdk\CLIPasswordSDK.exe"

arg = "GetPassword /p AppDescs.AppID=XXXXX-X-1 /p Query=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;Object=XXXXXXXX-USERID /o Password"

passw = os.system('prg arg') # I have this and as well below with subprocess

passw = subprocess.Popen([r'prg', 'arg'])

print(passw)
```

In command line below will work -

```
"D:\File\CyberArk\ApplicationPasswordSdk\CLIPasswordSDK.exe" GetPassword /p AppDescs.AppID=XXXXX-X-1 /p Query=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;Object=XXXXXXXX-USERID /o Password
```

Comment: You're printing pass, but store the result in passw. Typo only in the question, or is the typo also in the code you run?

Comment: @ErikBotö - Apologies, it was typo in question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tries to execute prg arg in the CMD, simpy remove the '

passw = os.system(prg + " " + arg)

should work

Comment: When i try this arg gets just added with prg, there should be a space because the executable expects argument with a space.

Comment: os.system(prg + " " + arg)

Comment: Thank you heaps. I had used this. I am running out in a problem The password is displaying in console... I tried to save in variable but its always printing in console, the argument /o Password is printing it. Is there a way to save the console output to a variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output